# as3 parse a string into URLVariables

Tags: actionscript-3, urlvariables

for instance if a string is

```
data = "success=0"
```

or

```
data = "success=1&registration=20";
```

how to parse all variables into URLVariables class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(data);
```

or

```
urlVars.decode(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If i remember right this will solve your problem.

```
var urlvar:URLVariables = new URLVariables(data);
```